# open children and close other children in multi-level navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a navigation and now managed to open up deeper levels of a certain parent one by one on click but I have a hard time trying to figure out how to close all others when going into a another direction.

Let's say you have A1, A2A, A3A and A4A open and you click on B1, then I want A1A, A2A and A3A to close. But it also needs to work midway: let's say you have A1, A2A, A3A and A4A open but you click on A2B then A3A and A4A need to close.

```js
$('li.has-children').click(function(){

        $(this).children('.wrap').addClass('active');
        
    });
```

```css
.wrap {
  display:none;
}

.active {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a class="">link A1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a class="">link A2A</a>
        <div class="wrap wrap-1">
        <ul>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a class="">link A3A</a>
            <div class="wrap wrap-2">
              <ul>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a class="">link A4A</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a class="">link A2B</a>
        <div class="wrap wrap-1">
        <ul>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a class="">link A2B</a>
            <div class="wrap wrap-2">
              <ul>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a class="">link A3B</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a class="">link B1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
    <ul>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a class="">link B2A</a>
        <div class="wrap wrap-1">
        <ul>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a class="">link B3A</a>
            <div class="wrap wrap-2">
              <ul>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a class="">link B4A</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a class="">link B2B</a>
        <div class="wrap wrap-1">
        <ul>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a class="">link B3B</a>
            <div class="wrap wrap-2">
              <ul>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a class="">link B4B</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the additional rule to remove the active class using `closest` and `not(this)`

```
$(this).closest('ul').children('li').not(this).children('.wrap').removeClass('active');
```

```js
$('li.has-children').click(function() {
  $(this).children('.wrap').addClass('active');
  $(this).closest('ul').children('li').not(this).children('.wrap').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a class="">link A1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a class="">link A2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children">
                <a class="">link A3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children">
                      <a class="">link A4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a class="">link A2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children">
                <a class="">link A2B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children">
                      <a class="">link A3B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a class="">link B1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a class="">link B2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children">
                <a class="">link B3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children">
                      <a class="">link B4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children">
          <a class="">link B2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children">
                <a class="">link B3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children">
                      <a class="">link B4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this does work great and was what I was looking for! i did notice that the other children stay open and it technically doesn't "reset", so lets say A1 - A4A are all open, then you click on B1 (they close) but when you click on A1 again you can see the whole trail to A4A still